# 'somewhere' gives error : No module named 'where' for my django app

Tags: python, django, module

- **When I **import** ( like below *after doing pip install somewhere* ) **handle_uploaded_file** from '**somewhere** library on my linux
  machine.)***

> `from somewhere import handle_uploaded_file`

---

Getting following **error** when trying to **run** my **django** application.)-

[image]

Comment: Please do not post code as image

Comment: Thanks , I would like to follow in future.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I scared previous person that provided a correct answer as it was deleted, but
I'm gonna guess you are following [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/file-uploads/). As you can see, there is a clear comment that it is supposed to be **imaginary** function, i.e. one that you need to implement yourself if you want to use it in the actual code. It's not supposed to refer to [somewhere module](https://pypi.org/project/somewhere/) which does not offer any function of that name.

```
# Imaginary function to handle an uploaded file.
from somewhere import handle_uploaded_file
```

Comment: Thanks, error comes exactly after doing this.